# How do I deter drain flies?

Tags: toilet, exterior, pest-control, insect

I have a small garden and beside it there is a small toilet. There are always many drain flies stuck on the door and inside the toilet walls. Somebody gave me a suggestion to make soap water and spray it on them, but it did not work.

How can I make them fly away for ever? What solution or chemicals can work on them?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try pepper extract. Crush very hot peppers in water, let soak, then filter. Wipe this onto a test area and see if this repels the flies.

Or just use pesticide spray on the walls. Use one of the fairly non-persistent products that contain chlorpyrifos or chlorpyrifos-methyl or permethrin. If the flies are getting in around a loosely fitting door, you might get some control just spraying the edge of the door and the jamb.

Answer (score 1):

Are you USING this toilet?  The best thing would be add lots of lime and fill it in...I am assuming this is an outhouse and not attached to the city sewer.  Too cute.

He (she) is called drain fly or bathroom fly or moth fly.  Psychodidae, Clogmia albipunctata, used to be in Pericoma.

Get rid of the problem get rid of these cute flies.  If you were to go in like Ghost Busters and spray stuff to kill them all, these same flies would find this bathroom of yours and fill it up again.

Of course you knew all of this...

Comment: In Louisiana it was common to have an outside toilet to be used when one (OK, to be honest, one's employee) was working in the muddy garden. I assume the poster is referring to a flush toilet and not a pit.

Comment: Can't imagine a flush toilet hooked up to city sewer would attract flies.  I love this kind of thinking.  If you kill the flies you solve your problem...oh man.  There are billions that will come inhabit the niche where the others were killed.  Get rid of the problem you get rid of flies or just live with them.  Porta potty!!  Definitely will be in any city's regulations.  If one uses capsasin or hot pepper dust guess what will happen?  Someone will get it on their hands and have to go to hospital...think home insurance!! Don't remember hot peppers having any effect on insects, grins!!

Comment: A cheap solution would be to purchase a bag of pellets for burning in pellet stoves.  Mix half a bag in a big 20 gallon plastic tub with half as much water.  Allow to absorb.  When someone goes poo or pee they just take a few handfulls of this sawdust  to throw on top of the business.  Eliminates smell and flies but NOT completely.  To discard, start a compost pile JUST FOR THIS sawdust and poo poo.  AWAY from human interaction. Turn it often.  Makes incredible mulch for non food crops or ornamentals.  Oh yes, no toilet paper.  That needs a separate easy to open and close bin.